# Is there a way to pull labels from a separate table in tbl_summary?

Tags: r, tidyverse, plyr, gtsummary

I am using tbl_summary from the gtsummary package to create publication tables summarizing long lists of categorical data from a data table. For publication purposes, tbl_summary allows assigning human readable variable labels instead of variable names using the argument

```
label = grade ~ "Tumor Grade"
```

and for multiple variables in the form of a list:

```
label = list(api00 ~ "API in 2000",
             api99 ~ "API in 1999",
             api98 ~ "API in 1998")
```

However, I have hundreds of variables and the variable names with the corresponding human readable lables are stored in another table altogether.

How can I create a list of the format above (ie. var_name ~ "Variable label") from a separate table with those values and pass it into tbl_summary label as argument?

In other words, I have a table of the format:

```
VAR_NAME   VAR_LABEL
var1       First variable
var2       Second variable
...        ...
var159     Hundred fifty ninth variable
```

Is there a way to read this table and pass the arguments to the label function of tbl_summary as a list:

```
label = list(VAR_NAME ~ "VAR_LABEL")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're best bet will be to save the variable labels as a named list. They are a bit easier to work with, and you can pass the named list to any label argument in gtsummary.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.3.6'

list_of_labels <-
  list(age = "Patient Age, yrs",
       grade = "Path. Tumor Grade")

tbl <-
  trial %>%
  select(age, grade) %>%
  tbl_summary(label = list_of_labels)

# convert a data frame into a list
data.frame(variable = c("age", "grade"),
           label = c("Patient Age, yrs", "Path. Tumor Grade")) %>%
  tibble::deframe() %>%
  as.list()
#> $age
#> [1] "Patient Age, yrs"
#> 
#> $grade
#> [1] "Path. Tumor Grade"
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. This approach works. It's particularly useful because I have now developed a separate table (imported from a file) that I use as a 'rules dictionary' for each variable, enabling me to define not just the labels for each variable, but also force the "type" modifier (eg 'continuous' vs 'continuous2') and select the number of digits on a per-variable basis. I suspect the "sort" and "statistic" modifiers can be similarly defined on a per-variable basis using this approach, though I haven't yet implemented this.

Comment: You're correct. Any argument in a gtsummary function that takes a list of formulas will also accept a named list (where the names are the variable names). The reason for the formulas is to take advantage of the selectors, like `all_continuous()` and `starts_with()`. Internally the selecting formulas are immediately converted to named lists.

Answer (score 1):

It's been some time, but just in case anyone is looking for a way to pull the labels from a lookup/codebook table for gtsummary tables, below is a reproducible example, inspired by prior responses.

First, I created a lookup/codebook table as a data frame with the variable name as one column and the corresponding label as another. The underlying data used in this example is Iris, which comes with your default RStudio.

```
# create lookup table 
labels <- data.frame(
      variable_name = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length"),
      Label = c("Sepal.Length: this", "Sepal.Width: that", "Petal.Length: other"))
```

Then I created the list of labels in the format required by gtsummary, which is a list of unnamed lists containing formulas.

```
# set labels 
formula_list <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(labels)), function(i) {
      as.formula(sprintf('%s ~ "%s"', labels$variable_name[i], labels$Label[i]))
})
```

To make things easier, I also extracted a second element from the formula, i.e., the variable name. That way, the variable names can be used in the `include` argument of the `tbl_summary` function.

```
# get label names 
lab_names <- unlist(lapply(formula_list, function(formula) {
      as.character(formula[[2]])  
}))
```

Lastly, I created the table inputting the previously created list of labels and vector of variable names.

```
# create table 
iris %>% 
      gtsummary::tbl_summary(
        include = lab_names, 
        label = formula_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the labels dynamically using `Map`. If your dataframe is called `df`, try :

```
formula_list <- Map(function(x, y) as.formula(sprintf('%s~"%s"', x, y)), 
                    df$VAR_NAME, df$VAR_LABEL)
```

Then use this `formula_list` in `label`.

```
label = formula_list
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately it isn't working. This approach seems to generate a list of type character whereas tbl_summary label function requires input list of type formula.

Comment: Is there perhaps a different approach using the package "labelled" or the apply_labels function? tbl_summary would recognize this according to documentation.

Comment: @sk454 I forgot to include `as.formula` in the answer. Try the updated answer.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your effort. This must be close but the behavior is very perplexing. I am pasting the output of your approach (first three elements of the list with my actual fields): > formula_list
$sex
sex ~ "Sex"
<environment: 0x00000283b6cd1ff8>

$age
age ~ "Age"
<environment: 0x00000283b6ccafc8>

$dx_type
dx_type ~ "Heart failure etiology"
<environment: 0x00000283b5fa4dc0>

Comment: and this is the manual list that works as expected: > listoflabels
[[1]]
sex ~ "Sex"

[[2]]
age ~ "Age"

[[3]]
dx_type ~ "Heart failure etiology"

Comment: the error I get with your approach (which seems like it should work because it generates what looks to be the correct string) is Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `var_label`.
x Result 1 must be a single string, not a vector of class `formula` and of length 3

Comment: Is it possible for you to add a reproducible example using which I can test my answer ?